# Short vs Long brake pads (with v-brakes) on road bike rims at high speed

Tags: brake-pads

Would v-brakes with the normal v-brake long pads (as opposed to shorter brake pads) on road rims exhibit any problematic behavior going downhill at speeds of 50 mph?  I am concerned that the longer brake pad may be more susceptible to shudder and/or grabbiness than shorter pads.

Background:

The bike in question is a Surly Cross Check which is set up with brake posts for cantilever or v-brake.  Caliper is not an option.

The brakes I have ready to put on are Deore XT br-t780 (with long brake pads) , front and back.

Other v-brakes with shorter pads are available, e.g., Shimano BR-M422.  (But these M422 are much lower quality than the T780 - and the question is about long vs short pads, not quality of the brakes they come with).

The cable travel in the lever is not an issue as I have the problem solver travel device ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have a problem.

In fact it should be easier to set the toe as well as the alignment. Assuming the block widths are about the same, you should see better stopping power as well as cooling.

I go long, esp. cause I'm +90kg and enjoy speed.

Shudder and "grabbiness" are typical toe issues. If you follow the pad instructions or any of the hundreds of guides available online, you'll get real good at setting the toe and get the most out of them.

It is the most common issue I fix for friends who's "bikes don't work".

Comment: Exactly the answer I was hoping for - experience with the speed/long combination.  Thanks.